# SQL Query to fetch data from 4 different tables

Tags: sql, mysql-5.5

I have four tables and I need to fetch data from one table with where condition and the output contains ID's from three different tables using those ID's need to get the names of them.

```
Company:
CompanyID - PK
CompanyName
CompanyDescription

Users:
UserID - PK
FirstName
LastName
Email

TaskDetails:
TaskID - PK
CompanyID - FK of Company.CompanyID

TaskStatus:
TaskStatusID - PK
TaskID - FK of TaskDetails.TaskID
Status
Details
CreatedBy - FK of Users.UserID
UpdatedBy - FK of Users.UserID
CreatedAt
UpdatedAt
```

Need a query to return something like below:

`CompanyName,Email,Status,Details,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt with where condition on TaskStatus table  TaskStatus.UpdatedBy!=1 and TaskStatus.UpdatedAt>'2013-08-01' and TaskStatus.status='COMPLETED'`

Comment: MySQL documentation on join syntax:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: @Phil / @RFL  Please check whether the below query is correct... `Select CM.CompanyName as CompanyName, U.Email as User, TS.Status as Status, TS.Comments as Comments, TS.CreateDate as CreateDate, TS.UpdateDate as UpdateDate FROM 
 TaskStatus as TS
 LEFT JOIN TaskDetails as TD ON TD.TaskID = TS.TaskID
 LEFT JOIN Company as CM on CM.CloudID = TD.CloudID
 LEFT JOIN Users as U on U.UserID = TS.UpdatedBy
 WHERE
 TS.CreateDate>'2013-08-01' and TS.UpdatedBy!=1 and TS.Status='COMPLETED'
 GROUP by CM.CompanyName, U.Email;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select CM.CompanyName as CompanyName, U.Email as User, TS.Status as Status, TS.Comments as Comments, TS.CreateDate as CreateDate, TS.UpdateDate as UpdateDate
FROM 
 TaskStatus as TS
 LEFT JOIN TaskDetails as TD ON TD.TaskID = TS.TaskID
 LEFT JOIN Company as CM on CM.CloudID = TD.CloudID
 LEFT JOIN Users as U on U.UserID = TS.UpdatedBy
WHERE
 TS.CreateDate>'2013-08-01' and TS.UpdatedBy!=1 and TS.Status='COMPLETED'
GROUP by CM.CompanyName, U.Email;
```